# Rspec GET doesn't match route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm testing a controller in my application and have the following code in my controller:

```
describe CsdlController do
    describe "GET /csdl/inclusive" do
        before do 
            # Create domains that are included
            @domain = create(:validated_domain)
        end
        it "returns a CSDL with valid domains" do
            get "/csdl/include.json"
            response.body.should =~ /#{@domain.text}/
        end
    end
end
```

I also have the following route:

```
match "/csdl/:type" => 'csdl#show'
```

However when I run the specs it gives me the following error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"csdl", :action=>"/csdl/include.json"}
```

I have a feeling that I'm using RSpec incorrectly here but not sure how to solve it.  Any ideas?

I should add that it seems to work perfectly when I actually call it through my browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In controller tests you call actions via name not via route paths:

```
get :show, type: 'include', format: 'json'
```